# What's the latest status of QueryDSL?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, querydsl

It's over a year that we have had a commit for QueryDSL.
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl
 Shall we consider this project Dead or is it moving to a new group? I guess the old team have no plan to maintain it anymore. New JDKs arrive every 6 months and I guess this project will be out of date sooner than we expect. Any news or compatible alternative?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I joined the querydsl team several years ago but lost interest due to the time constraints of having a full time dev job. I am however still a member of their Slack workspace and as of today, no-one has posted in the `#general` channel since July 2018. When I was active, the channel was busy most, if not every day.

I'm led to believe that Timo Westkämper (owner) is too busy / has lost interest, as with most (all?) other devs excluding Ruben Dijkstra who has contributed a great deal towards the project but is busy with University. He intends to come back. I heard that Atlassian started contributing but there was no-one to up-skill them and deal with their prs, so they ducked out.

In summary, AFAIK, no-one is working on the project and it would appear the owner has lost interest. I'm considering JOOQ but worry it's somewhat of a one-man-band too. If Lukas moves on, we could be in a similar situation.

I think querydsl is a great tool and it's free for all RDBMS, compared with better maintained JOOQ. In my personal opinion, I'd like to see, minimally, `querydsl-sql` forked by the open source community, its dependencies reduced (it brings in a *lot* for what it is) and its Java version brought up to date. Perhaps `querydsl-jpa` could follow. These, IMO, are by far the most used jars and the more specialised functionality could be dropped, E.G.

- `querydsl-collections`
- `querydsl-hibernate-search`
- `querydsl-jdo`
- `querydsl-lucene*`
- `querydsl-mongodb`
- `querydsl-scala`
- `querydsl-spatial`
- `querydsl-sql-spatial`
- `querydsl-sql-spring`

**UPDATE**

Timo has [approved the handover](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2459) of the project.

**UPDATE**

The querydsl team is back in action with querydsl 4.2.2 in Maven central as of 22-Nov-2019 and querydsl 5 in the pipeline. Thank you to the new team members for breathing life into this excellent project.

Comment: That project shouldn't be abandoned like this. I'm eager to spend sometime on that if there is a proper plan/road-map and you also have time. ;-)

Comment: I'm very sorry about the state of QueryDSL. It was a great competition, 5 years ago. Our two products (and its users) mutually benefitted from each other. Rest assured, Data Geekery is doing very well, we're expanding (2 people in Q2 2019, planning on hiring another person by Q4), we'll be creating new products around jOOQ, so we're very far from a similar situation!

Answer (score 0):

querydsl 5.0.0 is now dead again. There appears to be a new active fork at: https://github.com/OpenFeign/querydsl that has already released a 5.2 version and is working on a 6.0.0 release. Maybe spring-data and other spring projects that use querydsl should switch to this new active fork?