# When will next release of querydsl after 5.0.0 come out?

Tags: querydsl

There is a minor issue in the querydsl-bom and querydsl-root pom files where they refer to the artifact querydsl-codegen-utils, but they should actually refer to just codegen-utils. It looks like this has been fixed in the main branch. It's been two years since the last release. Any clue when a new release will be made to address this, and hopefully upgrade all the dependencies/plugins etc. that have been updated in the last 2+ years?

Currently, when using dependency:go-offline, for example, it can't download all the referenced artifacts. Apparently this issue has been reported before via the question: "Maven - querydsl-codegen-utils:pom:5.0.0 was not found", but no one answered the question. The answer is that the two pom files reference the wrong artifact name and need to be fixed to make the issue go away.

Pushing out an update would fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the latest status of QueryDSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668960/whats-the-latest-status-of-querydsl). See also: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2459#issuecomment-1837567963